# C# LINQ to XML - How can I filter nodes based on a child element?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Given the following XML (partial for brevity), I am attempting to only create a new object if the VALUE element for a CELL element where name is C006 is not a given value.

```
<alv:AREAS>
    <alv:TABLE>
        <alv:COLUMNS>
        <alv:ROWS>
            <ROWNUMBER>9 </ROWNUMBER>
                <ROW type="D" index="0 ">
                <ROW type="D" index="8 ">
                    <CELL name="C001" visible="X" imagefirst="" imageid="0001"/>
                    <CELL name="C002" visible="X">
                        <VALUE>A7F30024579</VALUE>
                    </CELL>
                    <CELL name="C003" visible="X">
                        <VALUE>Xfrmr 40VA,120-24V,single hub,Class II U</VALUE>
                    </CELL>
                    <CELL name="C004" visible="X">
                        <VALUE decimals="0">3</VALUE>
                    </CELL>
                    <CELL name="C005" visible="X">
                        <VALUE>PTO</VALUE>
                    </CELL>
                    <CELL name="C006" visible="X">
                        <VALUE>BANC</VALUE>
                    </CELL>
                </ROW>
        </ROWS>
    </COLUMNS>
</TABLE>
```

I thought the following might give me what I am looking for but I think I am trying to apply the filter one level too high (focus on the select for CELL). Without the filter, my list is created as expected. With the filter in place, there are no elements to further select.

```
var rows = xml.Descendants(ns + "ROWS")
            .SelectMany(row => row.Elements("ROW")).Where(r => r.Attribute("type").Value == "D")
            .Select(c => c.Elements("CELL")).Where(f => f.Attribute("name").Value == "C006").Select(v => v.Element("VALUE").Value != "LEIS"))
            .Select(d => new SAPDevice
            {
                MaterialNumber = d.Where(cell => cell.Attribute("name").Value == "C002").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE").Value).First(),
                PartNumber = d.Where(cell => cell.Attribute("name").Value == "C011").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE").Value).First(),
                Quantity = System.Convert.ToInt32(d.Where(cell => cell.Attribute("name").Value == "C004").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE").Value).First()),
                Price = System.Convert.ToDecimal(d.Where(cell => cell.Attribute("name").Value == "C008").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE").Value).First()),
                Description = d.Where(cell => cell.Attribute("name").Value == "C003").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE").Value).First()//,
                //MaterialType = d.Where(cell => cell.Attribute("name").Value == "C006").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE").Value).First()
            }).ToList();
```

I think the '.Where' needs to be applied to d but I am unsure how. Thanks for taking a look.

edit 7/19:
The following query returns all rows regardless of the filter value:

```
var rows = xml.Descendants(ns + "ROWS")
            .SelectMany(row => row.Elements("ROW")).Where(r => r.Attribute("type").Value == "D")
            .Select(c => c.Elements("CELL")).Where(f => !f.Elements("CELL").Any(f1 => ((string)f1.Attribute("name") == "C006") && ((string)f1.Element("VALUE") == "BANC")))
            .Select(d => new SAPDevice
            {
                MaterialNumber = d.Where(cell => cell.Attribute("name").Value == "C002").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE").Value).First(),
                PartNumber = d.Where(cell => cell.Attribute("name").Value == "C011").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE").Value).First(),
                Quantity = System.Convert.ToInt32(d.Where(cell => cell.Attribute("name").Value == "C004").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE").Value).First()),
                Price = System.Convert.ToDecimal(d.Where(cell => cell.Attribute("name").Value == "C008").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE").Value).First()),
                Description = d.Where(cell => cell.Attribute("name").Value == "C003").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE").Value).First()//,
                //MaterialType = d.Where(cell => cell.Attribute("name").Value == "C006").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE").Value).First()
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Put the where at the end : Where(x => x.MaterialType != "C006").ToList();

Comment: Is it possible to do this without relying on the MaterialType property of SAPDevice? I added that as a temporary measure while trying to figure this out and would prefer to remove it.

Comment: Try this : .Where(f => !f.Elements("CELL").Any(f1 => ((string)f1.Attribute("name") == "C006") && ((string)f1.Element("VALUE") == "LEIS")))

Comment: The where statement above seems to have no filtering effect as is (all results are still available) and filters everything (nothing returned at all) if changed to .Where(f => f.Elements("CELL") ...

When stepping through the code using the .Where(f => f.Elements("CELL") I can manually step through each row but never get a "returned true" from lambda f. When stepping through the Where statement as provided, I can only step through the first row before moving on to the last select statement.

Comment: The where I posted will remove rows when C006 equals "LEIS".  You may want to try with your posted data and change where from "LEIS" to "BANC".

Comment: Would you mind double checking the update I made to the original post? The filter, regardless of value I am looking for, is not filtering out anything. I get the entire list back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication120
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = xml.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("alv");

            var results = xml.Descendants(ns + "ROWS").SelectMany(rows =>
               rows.Descendants("ROW").Where(r => r.Attribute("type").Value == "D")
               .Where(f => !f.Elements("CELL").Any(f1 => ((string)f1.Attribute("name") == "C006") && ((string)f1.Element("VALUE") == "LEIS")))
               .Select(d => new SAPDevice()
               {
                   MaterialNumber = (string)d.Elements("CELL").Where(cell => (string)cell.Attribute("name") == "C002").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE")).FirstOrDefault(),
                   PartNumber = d.Elements("CELL").Where(cell => (string)cell.Attribute("name") == "C011").Select(val => (string)val.Element("VALUE")).FirstOrDefault(),
                   Quantity = (int?)d.Elements("CELL").Where(cell => (string)cell.Attribute("name") == "C004").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE")).FirstOrDefault(),
                   Price = (decimal?)d.Elements("CELL").Where(cell => (string)cell.Attribute("name") == "C008").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE")).FirstOrDefault(),
                   Description = (string)d.Elements("CELL").Where(cell => (string)cell.Attribute("name") == "C003").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE")).FirstOrDefault(),
               //     //MaterialType = d.Elements("CELL").Where(cell => cell.Attribute("name").Value == "C006").Select(val => val.Element("VALUE").Value).First()
               })).ToList();
        }

    }
    public class SAPDevice
    {
        public object test { get; set; }
        public string MaterialNumber { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
        public int? Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal? Price { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }


}
```